# Problema con herencia en modelos de Django

Tags: python, django

En mi aplicación de Django estoy trabajando con calendarios. Para mis fines tengo que utilizar las clases `Event` y `Occurrence` del módulo Django-Scheduler pero agregándole campos nuevos. Quisiera saber cómo heredar de esas clases para construir mis propios modelos y agregarle más campos además de los que traen las clases padres.

Yo intenté hacer esto en mi archivo models.py:

```
from schedule.models import Event, Occurrence

class Evento(Event):
    evento_padre = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Ocurrencia(Occurrence):
    plan = models.ManyToManyField(Plan)
```

Pero cuando ejecuto el manage.py makemigrations me da este error:

> SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
>
> ERRORS:
>      calendario.Evento.event_ptr: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Event', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
>      calendario.Ocurrencia.occurrence_ptr: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Occurrence', which is either not installed, or is abstract.

Comment: ¿Tienes la app que tiene esos modelos instalada?

Comment: ¿Agregaste `django-scheduler` a tus `INSTALLED_APPS` en settings.py?

Comment: Si, ese era el problema, pueden publicarlo como respuesta para puntuarla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy seguro, pero cuando el error te dice que la clase no está instalada, como dice tu mensaje de error: `'Occurrence', which is either not installed, or is abstract.` Quiere decir que `Django` no encuentra esa clase y esto puede ser porque no está agregada al `settings.py` en las `instaled_apps`.
Proba agregar `'django-scheduler'`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django-scheduler',
]
```